# Unable to build the Project with maven dependencies : xalan serialzer issues

Tags: maven

Unable to resolve the following issue in maven. I don't know whats wrong with the following :

Unable to build the Project when running the command :
**mvn clean install -DskipTests**

```
Dependency convergence error for xalan:serializer:2.7.1 paths to dependency are:

+-com.org:org-fixtures:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.org:org-engine:4.1-SNAPSHOT
    +-xalan:serializer:2.7.1
and
+-com.org:org-fixtures:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.pack:-seleniumcore:4.1-SNAPSHOT
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.21.0
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.21.0
        +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.9
          +-xalan:xalan:2.7.2
            +-xalan:serializer:2.7.2

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed
 with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for xalan:serializer:2.7.1 paths to dependency are:

+-com.org:org-fixtures:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.org:org-engine:4.1-SNAPSHOT
    +-xalan:serializer:2.7.1
and
+-com.org:org-fixtures:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.org:org-seleniumcore:4.1-SNAPSHOT
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.21.0
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.21.0
        +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.9
          +-xalan:xalan:2.7.2
            +-xalan:serializer:2.7.2
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude one of the xalan dependencies, probably the older one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>org-engine</artifactId>
  <version>4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xlan</groupId>
      <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do i need to exclude for each artifact id selenium-java, selenium-html-unit and for all those mentioned above. Because this does not resolve the problem. Is there any other way to put exclusion at one place only. I have various pom.xml linked to each other child pom, parent pom, parent to parent pom.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same error?  http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html suggests my solution should work!!

Comment: I am sure the error is still there.. but i don't know exactly in which pom do i need to put the exclusion.. there are multiple poms.